# Android Image Transition Animation overlays bars

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-animation, android-transitions

Image Transition Animation overlays bottom buttons or taskbar and statusbar.

Is there a way to fix it (make buttons and bars to be always on top)?

---

[image: Screen Record]

(On a tap on a item, the image overlays bottom buttons. The same happens on the top.)

---

Code:

```
String sharedElementName = getString(R.string.artist_image_transition);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
   .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, holder.imageView, sharedElementName);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Both images have:

```
android:transitionName="@string/artist_image_transition"
```

Part of styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

item xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artist_small_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/item_height"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_image_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_image_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/item_image_margin"
        android:transitionName="@string/artist_image_transition" />

    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try adding a marginTop to the image? I have the same problems with my listview so i added a margintop to that, but the bottom part i dont know how to fix.

Comment: I have added an item xml to the question, you can seen, that ImageView has android:layout_marginTop.

Comment: If you wish, you can see all the sources on [github repo](https://github.com/iskhakovt/yandex-test).

Comment: are you sure that item_image_margin works?

Comment: I have tried `android:windowActivityTransition`, it doesn't help. But adding toolbar and `navigationBarBackground` seems to work fine..

Comment: No, adding `navigationBarBackground` is extremely weird on orientation change.

Comment: Robbert, I don't understand. :( item_image_margin is just a const, android:layout_marginTop of the image is used to add some empty space between the top of the item and the image, so how can it help?

Comment: I understand but you are not providing what is in item_image_margin, so could be a misstype

Comment: Oh, ok, this const it set up.